# @@ERROR - How to process / evaluate in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

This update will fail as ID is Identity

But I am getting direct error message.
I am getting none of the PRINT statements.

How do I use @@ERROR?
Using SSMS.
Would you call this a script or a query?

```
PRINT   'start';
DECLARE @ErrorVal INT;
UPDATE IndenText SET ID = 7;
SELECT @ErrorVal = @@ERROR;
PRINT @ErrorVal;
IF @ErrorVal <> 0
BEGIN
    PRINT N'A error caught.';
END
PRINT 'done';
```

This also does not work from me

```
PRINT   'start';
DECLARE @ErrorVal INT;
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE IndenText SET ID = 7;
    SELECT @ErrorVal = @@ERROR;
    PRINT @ErrorVal;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'A error caught.' + @@ERROR;
    END
END CATCH
PRINT 'done';
```

I get
Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 
Cannot update identity column 'ID'.

As Martin stated it was a compile error.
Created a constraint that would not be a compile error.
And got the @@ERROR to process.

```
PRINT   'start';
DECLARE @ErrorVal INT;
DECLARE @newVal INT;
select  @newVal = -1;
BEGIN TRY
    update Twaste1 set ID = @newVal ;
    PRINT 'End Try';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Select @ErrorVal = @@ERROR;
    PRINT 'Begin Catch';
    IF @ErrorVal <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT CAST(@ErrorVal as varchar(30));
        PRINT N'A error caught.';
    END
END CATCH
PRINT 'done'
```

;

Comment: Agree with the answer to use try catch. That is a batch or scope aborting error. There is no particular logic as to which errors will abort the scope or just the statement that anyone has been able to discern AFAIK. See [Error Handling in SQL 2000](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#whathappens)

Comment: Ah actually after your edit I realise this is a compile time error. You can't even get an estimated execution plan for this. Compile time errors are only catchable if the compilation of the problem statement occurs after compilation of the main script. Usually because it happens at a child scope but may also happen if compilation of the statement is deferred.

Comment: @MartinSmith that explains why I am not even getting the first PRINT.  Correct I cannot even display and estimate execution plan. I need to find something that will fail but is not compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`TRY... CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead.  This will allow you to capture and examine the error thrown.

UPDATE:

I believe Martin already explained why this doesn't work in his comments to the original question, but I'll add a reference to the MSDN `TRY... CATCH` article:

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
>   they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from    running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such    as    object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because 
>     of deferred name resolution.

Answer (score 2):

For example For Update Use :

```
UPDATE HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
SET PayFrequency = 4
WHERE BusinessEntityID = 1;
```

IF @@ERROR = 547
    PRINT N'A check constraint violation occurred.';
GO